# How do I search and replace in a text document using SED?

Tags: regex, sed

I have a script for the R statistical package that I'm trying to modify using SED. Right now, it looks like this:

```
foo = [something unimportant]
summary(foo)
```

I'd like it to look like:

```
foo=[something unimportant]
print('foo')
summary(foo)
```

I've tried:

```
sed 's/summary\((.+)\)/print\(\'\1\'\)\nsummary\(\1\)/' <infile.txt >outfile.txt
```

but that seems to not work. I have the feeling my regex-fu is lacking. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `sed "s/summary(\(.*\))/print('\1')\n\0/" ...`. Sed uses posix regex, where ( and ) aren't special characters. Instead, groups are delimited by `\(` and `\)`.

Input:

```
foo = [something unimportant]
summary(foo)
```

Output:

```
foo = [something unimportant]
print('foo')
summary(foo)
```